# wiring for my timer switch

Tags: timer, wiring, wire, electrical, bad-wiring

I'm trying to wire as per the following wiring diagram.

[image: working diagram of timer switch]

I completed wiring as below, and timer is switching on, but at the programmed time, light is not switching on, anything wrong with wiring.

See the wiring that I did, shown below..

[image: my wiring]

[image: same wiring different view]

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, why my bulb is not glowing at the specified time in timer?

For user manual click below

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0819/3759/files/Euro_Controls_EDT811_822_digital_programmable_timer_Instruction_eManual.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi3h6HfrbTpAhUafSsKHTCdBfIQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0dRTUlIxtpP0U4aJpsoM1g

Comment: Looks right to me, assuming C1 is switching and not C2. Move the wire on pin 1 temporarily to pin 2 and see if the light comes on. If so, **remove all wires but power** and check that the the circuit between 1 and 2 is closing/opening using a multimeter.

Comment: Your wiring does not seem to match the diagram.  You don't seem to have an outside connection to Line 2. Exactly what is LIne 2?

Comment: There is no bulb in your bulb-holder!

Comment: (1) Can you confirm that an indication for C1 (channel 1) is showing on the display when you expect the relay to be on? (2) Can you confirm mains voltage between 2 and N? (3) Can you confirm voltage between 3 and N when off? (4) Can you confirm voltage between 1 and N when on? (5) Can you post a link to the user manual (not a catalogue page on the shopping page)? Hit the [edit] link below your post.

Comment: I have added user manual in the question edit

Comment: I actually don't know what is line 2 :(

Comment: @Barry The wiring diagram gives the option to use different live connections to power the timer itself (line 1) and to power the connected loads (line 2). If you don't need to use separate live connections it's fine to use a single live connection as shown in the pictures.

Comment: @Transistor I am unable to provide an answer for the same since I am in lockdown and device is not with me

Comment: @Barry make sense thanks

Comment: That extra wire from 2 to L is because is for an alternate line from generator backup in case of failure. Since the charge of capacitor might have lost since it was used for long, more than a year, I have bought it.